# How to suppress version warning from setup tools of python?

Tags: python, setuptools

We are using setup tools for creating command line version of the product, in python.

For that, added below code.

```
import click

@click.version_option()

@click.pass_context
def cli(ctx, platform, profile, debug):
    Log.configure_logger(Paths.state, debug)
    ctx.obj = Flags(platform, profile)
    print("test")
    if not exists(Paths.state):
        makedirs(Paths.state, mode=0o755, exist_ok=True)
```

When ran the main setup.py

from setuptools import setup

```
setup(
    name='someproduct',
    version='v1.15.0-eg-test',
    packages=["someproduct", "someproduct.commands"],
    install_requires=[
        'Click==8.0.3',
        'requests==2.27.1',
        'tabulate==0.8.9',
        'PyYaml==6.0',
        'tenacity==8.0.1',
        # below this the versions are just what i have
        'boto3>=1.21.0',
        'google-api-core>=2.5.0',
        'google-auth>=2.6.0',
        'google-api-python-client>=2.37.0',
        'oauth2client>=4.1.0',
        'google-cloud-storage>=2.0.0',
        'kubernetes==21.7.0'
    ],
    # TODO: once the platform is set at build, require only the gcp/aws-specific things
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': ['someproduct=someproduct.cli:cli']
    }
)
```

When ran the setup.py with version, it shows a warning message about version format.

How to skip the warning message to display.

```
python setup.py --version 
C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:501: UserWarning: The version specified ('v1.15.0-eg-test') is an invalid version, this may not work as expected with newer versions of setuptools, pip, and PyPI. Please see PEP 440 for more details.
  warnings.warn(
v1.15.0-eg-test
```

with compiled tool, getting this warning.

```
/usr/local/pipx/shared/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py:125: PkgResourcesDeprecationWarning: v1.16.6-mqa is an invalid version and will not be supported in a future release
  PkgResourcesDeprecationWarning,
```

Comment: The version string `v1.15.0-eg-test` is not conform to the standard [_PEP 440_](https://peps.python.org/pep-0440/), that defines the format for version strings in Python packaging. Is that a decision on purpose to not follow the standard?

Comment: yeah, it might be changed in the near future. But immediate fix is to suppress this warning message when the user tries to check for version.

Could you please suggest me on this @sinoroc